# makefile source file updates not propagating to target

Tags: makefile

i have this [makefile](https://github.com/normalize/www/blob/master/Makefile):

```
    jade = ./node_modules/.bin/jade
    nlz = ./node_modules/.bin/nlz

    build: build/index.js build/index.css build/index.html build/docs.html

    build/index.js: $(find client/*.js)
        $(nlz) build client/index.js

    build/index.css: $(find client/*.css)
        $(nlz) build client/index.css

    build/index.html: pages/home.jade pages/layout.jade
        $(jade) --path pages/home.jade < pages/home.jade > build/index.html

    build/docs.html: pages/docs.jade pages/layout.jade
        $(jade) --path pages/docs.jade < pages/docs.jade > build/docs.html

    node_modules:
        npm install

    clean:
        rm -rf build

    .PHONY: clean
```

however, when i update one of the `.js` or `.css` files, typing `make build` gives me `make: Nothing to be done for`build'.`. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should add `build` to the list of `.PHONY` targets.

Comment: then i lose the benefit of makefiles. absolutely terrible advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such make function as `$(find ...)`.

Since it's not a known function, make considers it to be a strangely-named variable which has never been set and so has no value: thus, the `build/index.css` and `build/index.js` have no prerequisites.  So as long as they exist, they're considered up to date.

Probably you wanted:

```
build/index.js: $(wildcard client/*.js)
        $(nlz) build client/index.js

build/index.css: $(wildcard client/*.css)
        $(nlz) build client/index.css
```

Comment: thanks! i guess it works to create vars but not as source targets

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; `$(find ...)` doesn't work anywhere, for anything, in GNU make.  It's not a valid function.  Maybe you were running `$(shell find ...)`, which will work but is not the same thing as you can see.